# Date time picker not saving the date

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

I have automated test that sets the date time picker, the date is changing but not saved
you can see the code here:

```
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(year, month + 1, day);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            string monthDate = dateTime.ToString("MMMM");
            string dayDate = dateTime.ToString("%d");
            string yearDate = dateTime.ToString("yyyy");
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

            _app.WaitForElement(x => x.Class("UIDatePicker"), timeout: timeout);
            if (today.Month < month + 1)
            {
                _app.ScrollDownTo(z => z.Marked(monthDate), x => x.Class("UIDatePicker").Index(0), timeout: timeout, strategy: ScrollStrategy.Auto);
            }
            else
            {
                _app.ScrollUpTo(z => z.Marked(monthDate), x => x.Class("UIDatePicker").Index(0), timeout: timeout, strategy: ScrollStrategy.Auto);
            }

            _app.Tap(x => x.Text(monthDate));

            _app.Query(x => x.Class("UIPickerView").Invoke("selectRow", 1, "inComponent", 1, "animated", true));
            if (today.Day < day)
            {
                _app.ScrollDownTo(z => z.Marked(dayDate), x => x.Class("UIDatePicker").Index(1), timeout: timeout, strategy: ScrollStrategy.Programmatically);
            }
            else
            {
                _app.ScrollUpTo(z => z.Marked(dayDate), x => x.Class("UIDatePicker").Index(1), timeout: timeout, strategy: ScrollStrategy.Programmatically);
            }

            _app.Tap(x => x.Text(dayDate)); 

            _app.ScrollUpTo(z => z.Marked(yearDate), x => x.Class("UIDatePicker").Index(2), timeout: timeout, strategy: ScrollStrategy.Programmatically);
            _app.Tap(x => x.Text(yearDate));

            _app.Tap("Done");
```

example when I try to set the date for 02/02/2020 :
[image]

and after I tap "Done":

[image]

I'm getting today's date but the year is 2020

Comment: Have you check you code? Does your code works well? Could do you provide your code for me to check with the UITest?

Comment: you mean the code of the picker ?

Comment: I want to now if there is any set for the year of the datapicker. According to the code you provided, what is the year you input for the dateTime?